# How to import using shp2pgsql?

Tags: shapefile, import

I want to import shapefile into PostGIS. There is one database `postgres` in it but no table added yet.

I am using this command:

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 districts.shp districts | psql -d postgres -U postgres
```

and it's giving me some error:

> Unable to convert data value to UTF-8 (iconv reports "Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character"). Current encoding is "UTF-8". Try "LATIN1" (Western European), or one of the values described at postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html

Is my command wrong ??

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have you tried `-W "latin1"` flag? Sometimes the default encoding (UTF-8) doesn't work well. Maybe you'll have better luck with latin1 encoding:

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 -W "latin1" districts.shp districts | psql -d postgres -U postgres
```

There's a useful cheat-sheet available [here](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide_20.bqg).

Hope it helps..

Comment: Hmm.. Have you correctly installed the PostGIS extension to the `postgres` database? If you haven't: maybe [this](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db_extensions) can help..

Comment: Usually if `make install` worked, you can move on to next process (`make check` is a step prior to `make install`).. If you can connect to your database via psql/pgadmin3 - that means your installation is a success. Can you move on to the "Create a spatial database" step? I recommend using the EXTENSIONS method..

Comment: Dude, this has strayed too far from your original question, haha.. It's a little hard to help you here when there's are a lot of variables at play: which version of PostgreSQL are you using?; on what kind of system?; and which version of PostGIS are you trying to install? It seems like it didn't recognize the `"CREATE EXTENSION"` syntax.. Does typing only: `psql -d geocoding -U postgres` gets you into the `geocoding` database successfully?

Comment: My bad. Then you should follow the [2.5. Create a spatially-enabled database on PostgreSQL lower than 9.1](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db) section.. If you still run into problems I'd suggest that you open a new question - so you can get better answers ;)