# Data export from Qgis to postgis

Tags: postgis, qgis-plugins

I have been trying to export my polygon shapefile from Qgis to postgis but have not succeeded.

I have tried such through the 'database' plugin of qgis but still have not got it.

I wish to know how I can do this, whether there is anything I need to do first in either postgis or Qgis before carrying out the process.

Comment: what exactly did you try? what went wrong? please be more precise in your question. in general, you need to create a DB connection and then e.g. use the import function in the DB manager

Comment: ok. thanks for your concern. To be precise, I have polygon shapefile layer of buildings which I created in Qgis and wish to save it in postgis. To do so, I was instructed by a friend to create in postgis a similar attribute table of the shapefile I wish to export before going to Qgis to make a connection, which I did. Going to Qgis, I deed the normal connection through the Postgis icon and then went to DB icon to do the export, but each time I try an error message appears. The error message is either that my table has no geometry or a similar table which am trying to export already exist.

Comment: the table will be created on import; choose the layer, mark the options for *primary key*, *geom column* (no need to change the values), *overwrite existing tables* (only the first time!) and *create spatial index*

Comment: I just deed so now, but still receives error message. How I wish I can be able to send u the interface of the error message which I snipped, I believe it will help more.

Comment: Below is exactly what the error message says:

Comment: Error 3
Creation of data source "PUBLIC"."table" failed: 
ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('PUBLIC','table',NULL,4326,'MULTIPO...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Try validating your geometries before putting them into the database. This happens to me sometimes when I accidentally make invalid geometries while editing them. (Under Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Validity) and try importing the result. I hope this works for you :)

Comment: Or try [shp2pgsql](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39238/how-to-import-using-shp2pgsql). It loads the shapefile into a postgis table. It's not within qgis but a possibility

Comment: ok. How do I get or download 'shp2pgsql', I believe it ought to come alongside postgres software, but it is not in mine.

Comment: have you installed the PostGIS extension in **your** db? (installing the product does not make it automatically available in a given DB)

Comment: No I have not done so

Answer (score 2):

To be able to use PostGIS functions in QGIS (or anywhere), you must first enable PostGIS in your database.

After having installed the binaries, you must log-in the DB (via psql command prompt, PGAdmin or else) and enable it:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis WITH SCHEMA public;
```

You can [read more](https://postgis.net/install/) on other extensions you may need