# Shapefile export issue

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, postgresql, shp2pgsql

Is there a geometry extension that can be enabled in PostGIS, in order to save Shapefile data in it?

I imported Shapefile  data in to PostGIS using shp2pgsql plugin, having the notion that PostGIS should automatically add geometry attribute to the data because it is a polygon data, but when I exported it to QGIS, the data appeared as just table with no geometry and I cannot work with it.

Please how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you saying that when you use the -g option in shp2pgsql, it doesn't put spatial information in the geometry field you designated?  Or are you saying it does put it in that geometry field, but doesn't export that geometry field with it to QGIS?

Comment: have you enabled Postgis in your DB?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280141/data-export-from-qgis-to-postgis

Comment: it does put it when I use the option, but doesnt export the geometry field with it to qgis

Comment: moreover, am still not so sure on how to enable postgis in my DB, as instructed

Comment: `create extension postgis;` will do that

Comment: If you can see the geometry in Postgis, but not in QGIS, it is likely that it is because you don't have a primary key or at least something that looks like a primary key. This is a major gotcha. Export from Postgis using pgsql2shp, load in QGIS, can't see anything.

Comment: I am guessing that if shp2pgsql worked for you, then Postgis must be enabled, which is why I made the comment above?

Comment: I enabled postgis on my DB, and it worked. Thanks friends @ Ian Turton, JGH, Baltok and John Powell aka Barça