# Shapefile to PostGIS via shp2pgsql.exe failed

Tags: shapefile

I am trying to import a shapefile to PostGIS via shp2pgsql.exe. 
I am not successful. I am only get the following message:

```
Importing with configuration: tune_aoi, public, geom, C:\Temp\TUNE_AOI.shp, mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=0
Shapefile type: Polygon
PostGIS type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]
Shapefile import failed.
```

Here's a link to the dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/325qlkeg3pez100/Temp.zip?dl=0

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look up this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39238/how-to-import-using-shp2pgsql