# Problem with massive data importation to PostGIS/PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, qgis-3, import

I need to import a huge SIG data into PostgreSQL (my shapefile table have **almost 1.700.000 rowns and 43 columns**).
I'm using **PostgreSQL 12.4 and PostGIS 3.0.x**, that came together with PostGIS Bundle 3 DBF Loader, which I'm using for the importation.

The thing is that my data is being loaded, at first look with no problem, but verifying the integrity of the table, I noticed the information are all messed up - with **column values misplaced between them** (the number of rows is aparently ok).

Does someone know the reason for that? **Is that a size limit for data to be sucessfully loaded from external environment into PostgreSQL/PostGIS?**

I'm new in this topic, and don't know what other information is important for someone to help me.

Comment: bundle 3 with postGis 2? it sounds like a version mismatch. Are you creating new tables or trying to import into an existing table?

Comment: i'm trying to import an existing table. And my PostGIS version is 3, I'm editing my question...

Comment: I guess that your problem is QGIS not PostGIS. QGIS can crash easily. Try shp2pgsql instead. It is a command line tool and easy to use. [How to Use shp2pgsql](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39238/how-to-import-using-shp2pgsql)

Comment: I'll try that! @milad  But my problem didn't needed QGIS to show up, Until now I'm using just PostGIS and PostgreSQL (of course the table was created in QGIS, but I can't imagine why it could have anything to do with the bug)

Comment: The "dbf loader" is a wrapper on shp2pgsql. You can try the `m` option to rename/remap the fields between the source shapefile and the DB table. I would personally just load the Shapefile in a new table (with all defaults from shp2pgsql-gui), then transfer/transform the data to the final (existing) table.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't much clear when describing the final aspect of the table. In the case is not like a "full" data misplacing, is just parts of the column that are migrating to a wrong column. In fact, because the size of the table, I coudn't check all of it. So I think it's even possible there is a pattern in this misplacing that I'm not perceiving.

Comment: I tried with shp2pgsql and after thousands "INSERT 0 1" it came with billions of errors like this: "fseek(-1221802801) failed on DBF file." in descendent counting.

Comment: Then it sounds like there is an issue with your dbf file that your initial load somehow hid for you. Have you tried to read the shapefile directly into qgis? I have personally been working with postgis tables with 4 million rows although not quite as many columns without any issues

Comment: Also try to import the non spatial data into postgres to see if that works. That could help you / us narrow down on what is the basic problem.

Comment: Also, could it be possible for you to upload your dataset somewhere so other people could test the import?

Comment: I've tried importing just the *DBF and had the same problem... About handing my files, seems a good idea, I'm lacking of ideas right now. I've uploaded a *RAR into this Google Drive folder.

 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zYEIEKFOtKUEScIIdPBC80TapXVBuQ5h?usp=sharing